# hover effect on navigation menu - border issue

Tags: html, hover, css

I need to create a menu same as this image [image]

My problem is the hover state where i need to  change the vertical image on both sides.
So far i've come to this point: http://jsfiddle.net/cgEab/

How can i change both left and right images on hover state?

The code for css is

```
#topmenu{
    float: right;
    position: relative;    
}
ul#topnav {
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none;   
    font-size: 1em;    
    background-color: #ccc;
}
ul#topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
ul#topnav li a {
    padding: 10px 22px;
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/az4oag1in/menu_bar_vertical.jpg');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block; 
}
ul#topnav li a.lastitem {
    background-image:none;    
}
ul#topnav li a:hover {
    color: red;
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/xch0azru7/menu_bar_vertical_hover.jpg');    
}
```

and the html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id="topmenu">
<ul id="topnav">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CUSTOMERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a class="lastitem" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which vertical image are you talking about? Ex on hover of SERVICES you want home and customer also to change???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the border image to double on both sides and subtracted the margin to correct for position.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3pQx/

```
ul#topnav li a {
    margin-left:-2px; <-- FIX
    padding: 10px 22px;
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/az4oag1in/menu_bar_vertical.jpg');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block; /* make the link background clickable */
}

ul#topnav li a:hover {
    color: red;
    background: url('http://s11.postimg.org/xch0azru7/menu_bar_vertical_hover.jpg'), url('http://s11.postimg.org/xch0azru7/menu_bar_vertical_hover.jpg'); <-- FIX
    background-position: left top, right top; <-- FIX
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; <-- FIX
}
```

Edited the fiddle made some fine tuning http://jsfiddle.net/LhFkf/

Comment: Exactly what i was talking about. I didn't have in mind this feature with the double image, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

may i sure try this

http://jsfiddle.net/cgEab/7/

CSS

```
 #topmenu{
    float: right;
    position: relative;    
}
ul#topnav {
   /* position: absolute;*/    
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    /*width: 640px;*/
    list-style: none;   
    font-size: 1em;    
    background-color: #ccc;

}
ul#topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    /*border-right: 1px solid #555;*/
}
ul#topnav li a {
    padding: 10px 22px;
    display: block;
    margin-left:-2px;
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/az4oag1in/menu_bar_vertical.jpg');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block; /* make the link background clickable */
}
ul#topnav li a.lastitem {
    background-image:none;    
}
ul#topnav li a:hover {
    color: red;


    background: url('http://s11.postimg.org/xch0azru7/menu_bar_vertical_hover.jpg'), url('http://s11.postimg.org/xch0azru7/menu_bar_vertical_hover.jpg');
background-position: left top, right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;


    }
```

Comment: Even I tried the same way, but if you see, left one misses to overlap which looks bad, he can use sliding doors technique here

Answer (score 0):

I've put the image to the `li`, before it was on the `li a`.
This is a css3 hack. I hope you don't have to use IE lower than 8.

```
#topmenu{
    float: right;
    position: relative;    
}
ul#topnav {
   /* position: absolute;*/    
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    /*width: 640px;*/
    list-style: none;   
    font-size: 1em;    
    background-color: #ccc;

}
ul#topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/az4oag1in/menu_bar_vertical.jpg');
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}

ul#topnav li:hover,
ul#topnav li:hover + li {
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/xch0azru7/menu_bar_vertical_hover.jpg')
    /*border-right: 1px solid #555;*/
}
ul#topnav li a {
    padding: 10px 22px;
    display: block;
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/az4oag1in/menu_bar_vertical.jpg');
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    display: block; /* make the link background clickable */
}
ul#topnav li:first-child {
    background-image:none;    
}
ul#topnav li a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgEab/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

'background-image' can take more than one image. So you could try something like this:

> background-image: url(...), url(...);
>
> background-position: left, right;